# Vendor folder missing after using brew to install Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, homebrew, drush

I am trying to install Composer and Drush on my Mac for my Drupal website, but am running into an issue whenever I try to actually run a Drush command.

I followed [these instructions](https://www.div.digital/article/how-install-homebrew-composer-and-drush-mac-osx-sierra) to download and install composer and Drush, however, when I go to run a Drush command I get an error saying Drush is not found.

I believe the main issue is that `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` does not work since my `.composer` directory doesn't have a `vendor` folder in it.

So somehow, when I ran `brew install composer` there was no `vendor` folder created, all that was created was a cache directory.

Why is the vendor folder missing after installing using brew?

Comment: at least, add your code to get solutions from others.

Comment: Which Drush? Starting from Drush 9 it only supports one install method now: That your Drupal 8 site is built with Composer and Drush listed as local dependency. You then can install [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) to have a Drush command that always uses the right local Drush, or a global (Drush 8 maybe) fallback you can define. Have you also already tried to call your Drush directly? `cd /my/drupal/ && ~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush status`? See https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ in general and the compatibility chart in special.

Comment: @leymannx oops, I forgot to include that. I am actually using Drush 8.1.17 for a Drupal 7.63 project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ensure composer is installed correctly

You have installed `composer` on your macOS system with the command:

```
brew install composer
```

Ensure composer is installed and found in your `PATH` by running:

```
which composer
composer --version
```

### Installing drush

1. Add composer's global `bin-dir` to your `PATH` environment variable

   ```
   export PATH="$(composer --global config --absolute bin-dir):${PATH}:"
   ```
2. Install `drush` with the following command:

   ```
   composer global require drush/drush
   ```
3. Verify `drush` has been installed correctly

   ```
   which drush
   drush --version
   ```

To persist the changes to your `PATH` add the line from `1.` to your shell's startup files (i.e. `~/.bashrc` for bash or `~/.zshrc` for `zsh`). Afterwards start a new shell-session.

Comment: Thanks, these seemed to work somewhat, however, now my drush command fails with a `mysql command not found`. Does this relate to the Drush installation

Comment: You need to install the `mysql-client` package which contains the `mysql` and `mysqldump` binaries. If you're on a debian based system run `sudo apt-get install mysql-client` or run `brew install mysql-client` if you're on macOS.

Comment: Ah, turns out that I was missing an `export` in my .zshrc file to point to the mysql running through MAMP.

Comment: Also, your solution worked other than `--global` not being recognized. You just need `composer global require drush/drush`

Comment: I fixed the `s/--global/global/` issue in my answer. Thanks for pointing out.